# How to fill a cell according to the type of number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Currently I have 2 suppliers with barcode scanning system in excel. Since I scan them in Column A in excel (with auto-enter to the next cell), I would like to know if it is possible to have automatically the name of the supplier on the relevant cell in column B. For example:

Supplier A has the barcode B00001019355
and Supplier B has the barcode .07642422

How can I make it to write down on cells B the "Supplier A" and "Supplier B" whenever I scan the respective barcode on excel, **based** on the type of letter that the barcode **starts** with (at the example is "B" and "." for Supplier A and B respectively) or with the **number of the letters/digits** in the barcode (12 in Supplier A and 9 in Supplier B).

Answer (score 1):

To use the first letter you can look for it and assign it like this -

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="B","Supplier A",IF(LEFT(A1,1)=".","Supplier B",""))
```

To count characters you can use something like this -

```
=IF(LEN(A2)=12,"Supplier A",IF(LEN(A2)=9,"Supplier B",""))
```